# cp Command Giving Error in Make file

Tags: shell, unix, makefile, gnu, gnu-make

HI while executing the below make file code  i'm getting  an error saying that ,

```
Signing File 3E0022__.FPG
cp: missing destination file  ******Error during cp command 
Try `cp --help' for more information.****
```

this is my script:

```
    for fpga in $(LIST_A); do\
            link=1;\
            for disFpga in  $(LIST_B); do\
                    if [ "$$fpga" = "$$disFpga" ] ;then\
                            echo "Signing File $$fpga";\
                            cp $($(fpga)) $(PKG)/$(fpga);\ ===> * Error at this Point*              
                               link=0;\
                    fi;\
            done;\
                    if [ $$link -eq 1 ] ;then  echo "Linking Done for $$fpga  File";\
                     fi;\
    done;
```

kindly help me  to resolve this issue

Thanks

Arun

Comment: $($(fpga)) is resolving to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting *Make* variables mixed up with *shell* variables. This will do what I think you want:

```
cp $$fpga $(PKG)/$$fpga;\
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `$($(fpga))` is wrong.  Should it be `$(fpga)`

Comment: I have tried but it is not working , Here i would like to add one comment  that , if i use 'foreach' cp command will work with the same code , but if i use for loop it wont work . I think for loop is shell construct and  foreach make construct.

Comment: Is this a shell script?  If so, variable substitution should be `${fpga}` not `$(fpga)`

Comment: No , i'm Doing this script on a gnu make file.

Comment: Can i use foreach here instead for .. or can anybody suggest me some other method to implement  the  same logic

Comment: If it's a make script, `$($(fpga))` recursively substitutes twice, which is why `cp` appears to only have one argument.  If it's a shell script, it's a syntax error.